# Cakephp sends email on behalf of, how to get rid of that

Tags: php, email, cakephp

How do i get rid of the "On behalf of" when sending mail from my cakephp shell script

Here i my email cake code

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array($contractResult['Entity']['email'] => $contractResult['Entity']['name']));
$Email->sender(array($contractResult['Entity']['email'] => $contractResult['Entity']['name']));
$Email->replyTo(array($contractResult['Entity']['email'] => $contractResult['Entity']['name']));
$Email->to('some@email.com');
$Email->subject('Invoice');
$Email->send('My message');
```

This results in an email with this from field in Outlook

User myusername [myusername@myserver.com]; on behalf of; DTDDussel vastgoed [from@email.com]

Comment: Set up valid SPF/DKIM.

Comment: Use SMTP instead of plain PHP mailer. That solves all those problems for the beginning.